# "This field is required" when GenericRelation field is marked as not required in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model set up with a GenericRelation named `tags`. The GenericRelation object defaults the `blank` kwargs attribute to True - so null is allowed at the Model Level:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    tags = GenericRelation(TaggableTag, content_type_field='taggable_type', object_id_field='taggable_id')
```

Within the serializer, I have attached a serializer to this tags field to ensure it's eager loaded on each request for Character information.

```
class CharacterSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tags = TaggableTagSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Character
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'date_of_birth', 'tags')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'tags': {'required': False, 'allow_null': True, 'default': None}
        }
        validators = []
```

As you can see, I've gone bit overkill on the validation rules, but all to just be doubly sure that it doesn't force the 'tags' field to be required.

However, the POST route seems to still return the following validation message:

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "tags": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

I'm unsure what to do here, I've followed the documentation on the Django Rest Framework [page about Validators](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#optional-fields) - I'm certain this might be because it's a GenericRelation field rather than a normal field, but I'm unsure how to solve it. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

It seems the serializer settings work both ways - GET and POST. On top of the validation options I've already provided on the serializer, I also needed to specify that the inclusion of the TaggableTagSerializer was optional - regardless of validation, the inclusion of the entire related serializer should be marked as optional.

I needed to change this line:

```
tags = TaggableTagSerializer(many=True)
```

to this:

```
tags = TaggableTagSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

Comment: I think the case here is a bit different. Normally, if you did not provide field definition explicitly, specifying the field as required: False in extra_kwargs would work, but when you declare a field explicitly, extra_kwargs for that field are ignored.